# Cannot properly bundle tests for Angular with HTML templates

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, karma-jasmine

At our current project, we built a custom hybrid NGJS/NGX application as interim step of wholly migrating to Angular.

The hybrid houses each Angular version in a separate catalog. They're interworking in both directions - we include downgraded Angular files in AngularJS and upgraded AngularJS files in Angular.

The build works exactly as expected (all the files are properly outputted), however, we cannot make the tests work (Karma + Webpack).

They fail at a very specific point - when you include AngularJS file that requires any type of HTML, e.g. `import Tpl from '../templates/my-template.tpl.html`.

The error is as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/ngjs/Account/templates/account.password.edit.tpl.html:4:16)
at Module../src/ngjs/Account/templates/account.password.edit.tpl.html (http://localhost:9879/absolute/path-to-repo/karma.bundle.js?b7d10f4cb57d9b36c6b149128e3c9810b2901be0:7594:1)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9879/absolute/path-to-repo/karma.bundle.js?b7d10f4cb57d9b36c6b149128e3c9810b2901be0:20:30)
at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/ngjs/Core/services/user.service.ts:11:64)
at Object../src/ngjs/Core/services/user.service.ts (http://localhost:9879/absolute/path-to-repo/karma.bundle.js?b7d10f4cb57d9b36c6b149128e3c9810b2901be0:7610:1)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9879/absolute/path-to-repo/karma.bundle.js?b7d10f4cb57d9b36c6b149128e3c9810b2901be0:20:30)
at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/ngx/core/components/display-groups-dropdown/display-groups-dropdown.component.ts:14:22)
at Object../src/ngx/core/components/display-groups-dropdown/display-groups-dropdown.component.ts (http://localhost:9879/absolute/path-to-repo/karma.bundle.js?b7d10f4cb57d9b36c6b149128e3c9810b2901be0:8092:1)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9879/absolute/path-to-repo/karma.bundle.js?b7d10f4cb57d9b36c6b149128e3c9810b2901be0:20:30)
at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/ngx/core/components/display-groups-dropdown/display-groups-dropdown.component.spec.ts:4:43)
```

(`ngx` being Angular part of the app and `ngjs` being AngularJS).

Our Karma config:

```
export default (config) => {
config.set({
    basePath: 'src',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
        karmaJasminePlugin,
        karmaChromeLauncherPlugin,
        karmaWebpackPlugin,
        tsLoaderPlugin,
        karmaMochaReporterPlugin,
        karmaCoverageIstanbulReporterPlugin,
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        '../karma.bundle.ts': ['webpack'],
    },
    client: { clearContext: false }, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    files: [
        { pattern: '../karma.bundle.ts', watched: false },
    ],
    mime: {
        'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx'],
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
        dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
        reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
        combineBrowserReports: true,
        fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: config.codeCoverage ? ['mocha', 'coverage-istanbul'] : ['mocha'],
    mochaReporter: { ignoreSkipped: true },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    singleRun: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    customLaunchers: {
        ChromeDebug: {
            base: 'Chrome',
            flags: ['--remote-debugging-port=9333'],
            debug: true
        },
    },
    webpack: config.codeCoverage ? webpackMerge(webpackConf,
        {
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.ts$/,
                        exclude: /\.spec\.ts$/,
                        enforce: 'post',
                        use: {
                            loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
                            options: {
                                esModules: true
                            },
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ) : webpackConf,
    webpackMiddleware: {
        noInfo: true,
        stats: 'errors-only'
    },
    concurrency: Infinity,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 210000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 210000,
});
};
```

Our tsconfig for the tests:

```
{
"extends": "../tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
        "jasmine",
        "node"
    ]
},
"include": [
    "../karma.bundle.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
]
}
```

`karma.bundle.ts` (rather standard):

```
// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
beforeAll(() => {
    testing.TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
    testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(browser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
        browser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
});

/**
 * Get all the files, for each file, call the context function
 * that will require the file and load it up here. Context will
 * loop and require those spec files here
 */
function requireAll(requireContext) {
    return requireContext.keys().map((key) => {
        requireContext(key);
    });
}

/**
 * Requires and returns all modules that match
 */
const context = (require as any).context('./src', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
console.log('Keys: ', context.keys());
requireAll(context);
```

So far, I have following suspicions:

- Karma doesn't see typings when loading the modules, hence HTML is not recognizable type
- Webpack doesn't process HTMLs as it should, despite having proper configuration, but only in Karma context

I'd be glad for any help, as we're completely stuck and our tests are unusable for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation we found a partial solution that allows tests to pass and ignores `module` errors. We modified our code for requiring context in Karma:

```
function requireAll(requireContext) {
    return requireContext.keys().map((key) => {
        try {
            requireContext(key);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Cannot require:', err);
        }
    }
}
```

Also worth mentioning: import order is important in bundle file (that was another problem we had with `karma.bundle.ts`). We switched from:

```
import * as testing from '@angular/core/testing';
import * as browser from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
```

to:

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';

import * as testing from '@angular/core/testing';
import * as browser from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
```

This doesn't solve our issue directly, but allows for tests to pass as long as imported templates that cause errors aren't used in the tests (all the import errors will be suppressed by `catch()` clause).

Another part of the solution was to modify Webpack config for tests - we added additional rule that processes HTML in the simplest possible way. It occured that Karma probably changed the paths that were used in Webpack pipelines and Webpack was not able to properly process HTMLs. This:

```
rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tpl\.html$/,
                use: [
                    'raw-loader',
                    'html-loader'
                ]
            },
            { // ts
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            configFile: path.join(srcDir, 'tsconfig.spec.json'),
                            onlyCompileBundledFiles: true,
                            experimentalWatchApi: true,
                            transpileOnly: true
                        },
                    },
                    'angular2-template-loader'
                ],
            },
        ]
```

solved the issue.